# Mark up to and including the character under the cursor

Tags: region, motion, mark, kill-text

By default, when I activate `mark` it just adds everything to the region up to the `point` which is behind the cursor (image below)

[image]

What I want to achieve, however, is to also include `-` as part of my region. It's especially helpful when I kill the region. Almost always when I jump to a target character (using `avy`), and kill the region, I miss the last character, which is what I jumped to.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs, the region is defined precisely (and only) as the stretch of text between point and the mark.  The only way to achieve what you want is to position point where you want the region to extend to.  The simplest, least automated way is to remember to execute `forward-char` (<kbd>C-f</kbd> in vanilla Emacs).

You may find these useful replacements for `forward-word` and `backward-word`:

```
(defun forward-to-word-boundary (arg)
  "Move forward until encountering the beginning or end of a word.
With ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (or (eobp)
      (re-search-forward "\\w\\b\\|\\W\\b" nil t arg)
      (goto-char (point-max))))

(defun backward-to-word-boundary (arg)
  "Move backward until encountering the beginning or end of a word.
With ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (or (bobp)
      (re-search-backward "\\b\\w\\|\\W\\b" nil t arg)
      (goto-char (point-min))))
```